# any synchronous storage that works with expo?

Tags: react-native

I am looking for some **syncronous** storage that I can use in a `react-native` application developed with `expo`.

I've seen some [references](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) but these do not yet work with expo yet.

Comment: Why can't you use AsyncStorage and await the action of writing/reading?

Comment: I am adapting a web based library of a considerable size to react-native, it uses `localStorage` in a massive way, using `AsyncStorage` would imply changing a big part of its source code to execute asynchronous calls, so I am looking for options to implement it in a more efficient way, something like [this](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv) the problem is, this library doesn't work with `expo`.

Comment: Well. The readme GitHub page states that it works with react-native. From my experience I can tell you that if it is working with react-native it also will work with expo. What issues are you facing when using it with expo?

Comment: I'm getting this error in expo app: `TypeError: _reactNativeMmkv.MMKV.getString is not a function. (In '_reactNativeMmkv.MMKV.getString(name)', '_reactNativeMmkv.MMKV.getString' is undefined)`, This is a library known [issue](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/issues/24), according to some comments this error happend whit hot-reloading is applied, but I obtain the same error simply run any of its methods.